# How to use softmax in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I made a TensorFlow sample which takes an integer and divides it by 5 and classified into the remainder.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1CQ5IKymDCuCzWNfgKQrZZSL3ifyzRJrA?usp=sharing

```
import numpy as np
from keras import models
from keras import optimizers
from keras import layers
from keras.utils import to_categorical

num_of_rows = 1500
num_of_classes = 5

X = np.abs(np.floor(np.random.randn(num_of_rows, 1)* 10000))
y = X % (num_of_classes)

X = X /100000

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(25, input_dim=1))
model.add(layers.Dense(25, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(25))
model.add(layers.Dense(num_of_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001),loss='categorical_crossentropy',)
model.summary()

X_normal = X.astype('float')
print(X_normal.shape)
test_label = to_categorical(y,num_classes=num_of_classes)
print(y[:5])
model.fit(X_normal, test_label, epochs=100, batch_size=10)
```

The loss does not decrease when running with the above link.

```
Epoch 1/100
150/150 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.6094
Epoch 2/100
150/150 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.6102
Epoch 3/100
150/150 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 1.6091
Epoch 4/100
150/150 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 1.6090
Epoch 5/100
150/150 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 1.6089
Epoch 6/100
150/150 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 1.6089
Epoch 7/100
150/150 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.6089
Epoch 8/100
150/150 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.6090
Epoch 9/100
150/150 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 1.6091
Epoch 10/100
150/150 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 1.6084
```

I need advice on what else I need to do

Comment: What actually do you want to do? 
You create random train values, i dont see how the loss should decrease there

Comment: I've created random train data x = [17,8,9,5]  and created label based on X. in this case, y = [2,3,4,0], simply y= x %5, and there is a rule and TensorFlow should find the rule. but the loss is not decreased. it means that my program can't find it

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, I found a solution.

the Input is just an integer and I think it is 1 dimension.
it looks like as follows
X = [100 , 15, 48, 17, 22]

I try the test input's shape as follow:
X = [[1,0,0] , [0,1,5],  [0,4, 8] , [0,1,7] , [0,2,2]]

The loss is decreased as expected